# Is it possible to get the referenced document at the same query in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I add the following data to Firestore

```
Collection(posts)
 |--- postA
       |--- user: DocumentReference(users/userA)
       |--- text: Hello apple
 |--- postB
       |--- user: DocumentReference(users/userB)
       |--- text: Hello orange

Collection(users)
 |--- userA
      |--- name: AAA
 |--- userB
      |--- name: BBB
```

And I call

```
Firestore.firestore().collection("posts").getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
    // get posts array
    let data = querySnapshot?.documents.data()
    for post in data {
        // get user of each post
        let userRef = post["user"]
        userRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
            // finally get the user....
        }
    }
}
```

The `user` document will not return with the `post` document directly. Only the `DocumentReference` of `user`. And if I need the `user` of every `posts`, it may caused too many requests.

Is it possible to get the `user` document of each `post` at the same query?

Answer (score 1):

No, document references are not followed automatically when fetching a document.  You will have to make a separate request for each document.